# JavaScript async returns 'then not defined'

Tags: javascript, ajax

Am new to async programming, have read similar threads which all seem to have the same problem of not returning anything, whereas mine does...?

However I am still getting the error message 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'

```
function getWorkItems(iterationPath, projectId) {

    var queryClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_QueryAPI.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient);
    var query = { query: "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItem WHERE [System.IterationPath] = '" + iterationPath + "'" };
    var resultOfQuery;

    queryClient.queryByWiql(query, projectId).then(

        function (resultOfQuery) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                resolve(resultOfQuery);
                console.log("Debug: " + JSON.stringify(resultOfQuery));
            })
            VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();

        });
}
```

The above prints the debug message fine, it gets the data from the server, then errors with this when I call it elsewhere

```
let bar;

getWorkItems(counter.path, projectId).then ( res => {
    bar = res;
    console.log("Debug: should be output of query " + JSON.stringify(bar));
})
```

Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: getWorkItems is returning undefined, not a Promise.

Comment: I thought my use of 'resolved' was dealing with that ...? How should it look, pls?

Comment: you are returning a new Promise inside of an anonymous function, but not to the outer function, getWorkItems.

Comment: probably queryByWiql doesn't return an promise. Try to `console.log` it.

Answer (score 2):

getWorkItems doesn't have a return statement in it, so it's implicitly returning undefined. Also, since `queryClient.queryByWiql(query, projectId)` is already returning a promise, you don't need to create a promise of your own and can do the following:

```
function getWorkItems(iterationPath, projectId)
{
  var queryClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_QueryAPI.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient);
  var query = { query: "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItem WHERE [System.IterationPath] = '" + iterationPath + "'" };
  return queryClient.queryByWiql(query, projectId);
}
```

If you wanted to keep that log statement and notifyLoadSucceeded in there, you can, but you still don't need to create your own promise. If you're in a .then callback, you just need to return the value that you want the promise to resolve as:

```
function getWorkItems(iterationPath, projectId)
{
  var queryClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_QueryAPI.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient);
  var query = { query: "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItem WHERE [System.IterationPath] = '" + iterationPath + "'" };
  return queryClient.queryByWiql(query, projectId)
    .then(function(resultOfQuery) {
      console.log("Debug: " + JSON.stringify(resultOfQuery));
      VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
      return resultOfQuery;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you v much. Frustrating but don't really know what I'm doing :(